# Worksheet_Change Macro with moving trigger cells

Tags: vba, excel, loops, find

**UPDATED**

I need to show or hide a worksheet based on the answer to a question in the sheet. If the answer is "Yes", then show the sheet. If "No", then hide it. So that part is easy...

Now, this question might exist multiple times on the sheet. If the answer to the question is "Yes" for ANY of the questions, then show the sheet; if ALL answers are "No", then hide the sheet. Assuming the questions and answers were always located in the same place that would be easy enough as well...

Where I get lost is, the question and answers cells could really be almost anywhere within the sheet and could also occur an infinite number of times (would likely never exceed 10... but it could).

So what I need, is a code that finds the question, OFFSETS(0,1), then triggers the macro if it equals the target.address. I can do that for the first time the question occurs in sheet, but if I answer the question further down, I can't get it trigger the macro.

Here is where I am now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
    If Target.Offset(0, -3).Value = "Additional Collateral?" Then
        Coll
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
    If Target.Offset(0, -3).Value = "Additional Collateral?" Then
        Coll
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

**

```
Sub Coll()

If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" Then
Sheets("Additional Collateral").Visible = True
Exit Sub
Else
Sheets("Additional Collateral").Visible = xlVeryHidden
End If

End Sub
```

This code does everything except If the answer is "Yes" for any of the "Additional Collateral?" questions I need the sheet to be visible. This code is only based on the most recent answer...

Comment: How do you identify which cells on the sheet contain the question of interest ??

Comment: The question is "Additional Collateral?" I use Cells.Find... to get find the question then OFFSET(0,1), which takes me to the answer. The every time I change the answer, it triggers the macro to run.

Comment: Why not directly check if the `Target` (the cell which got the change) is the yes/no cell and has your question to the left... this way only changed cells would be checked (which also is faster)???

Comment: I would be open to that if I am understanding you correctly... Do you have an example? Mind you, there are may other questions that have the answer of yes or no. "Additional Collateral?" is a more unique value. So either way i think i have to check both values.

Comment: Whenever `Worksheet_Change` is triggered the `Target` has a range which has been changed => if `Target` is "yes" or "no", check if `Target.Offset(0,-1)` is the *question*...

Comment: I have updated with a new code. I am getting a Type Mismatch error that I am working on, but is the what you mean Dirk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works just fine for my purposes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
    If Target.Offset(0, -3).Value = "Additional Collateral?" Then
        Coll
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
    If Target.Offset(0, -3).Value = "Additional Collateral?" Then
        Coll
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

**

```
Sub Coll()

Dim r As Range, cell As Range

Set r = Range("$X$1:X$1000")

For Each cell In r
    If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
        Sheets("Additional Collateral").Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Sheets("Additional Collateral").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    End If
Next

End Sub
```